# import netCDF4 error enthought canopy

Tags: python, enthought, hdf5, canopy

Trying to get *enthought canopy* working on mavericks and specifically *netCDF4* as I deal with this data format a lot.  However, getting this error when trying to import it:

```
import netCDF4
```

> ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>   ----> 1 import netCDF4
>
> ImportError:
>   dlopen(/Users/barry/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/netCDF4-1.0.5-py2.7-macosx-10.6-x86_64.egg/netCDF4.so,
>   2): Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/libhdf5_hl.7.dylib   Referenced
>   from:
>   /Users/barry/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/netCDF4-1.0.5-py2.7-macosx-10.6-x86_64.egg/netCDF4.so
>   Reason: image not found

Not sure if there is an environment variable that is blocking it or what.  Seems to be looking in the macports library but I've tried changing the `$PATH` variable to have the canopy path first however it didn't change anything.

Comment: Do you have $DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH or similar environment variable set? $PATH won't cause it but the dynamic loader paths could.

Comment: Or, do you have PYTHONPATH environment variable set? That could also interfere.

Comment: I do have python path set like so...export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/Users/barry/pythoncode also I tried to set the DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH as Users/barry/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib but it didn't work either